# Was used to be vs used to be?

Tags: grammar

'There was a time when he was our class representative.'

Which one is a proper replacement of the above sentence?

1) There was a time when he used to be our class representative.

2) There was a time when he was used to be our class representative.

I feel that the 1st one is correct.

Comment: "There was a time when" = "used to be" -- so avoid the duplication.

Comment: See also: [ell.se]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first sentence is grammatically correct, although redundant. I'd either say

> He used to be our class representative.

or

> There was a time when he was our class representative.

Both unambiguously imply that he is no longer our class representative.

The second sentence is marginally grammatically correct, but its meaning is rather strange:

> [We] used him as our class representative.

It is unlikely that this is your intended meaning.

Comment: Yes, it is very unlikely that he aimed for the passive construction in the second sentence. At the same time it is highly likely that he aimed for "was used to be***ing***" as in the past tense of "I am used to sprinting". Be(conjugated in time)+used to + something (e.g. gerund). As it is stated in my post with 4 references from M-W to OLD. Additionally my post has an explanation of the possible usage of the sentences and what they imply/convey and not to forget 3 downvotes.. Ha :D well...

Answer (score -3):

Yes, the first one is correct and conveys the same meaning as the original. It has *still* a slightly different meaning depening on context. Nevertheless it generally states the same.

> 1) There was a time when he used to be our class representative.

**The contextual difference of the original sentence and the first replacement:**
E.g. You would use "he used to be" if you want to express a nostalgic notion or a contradiction in his character development. He could have been a very enthusiastic pupil who used to be class representative but later came in contact with drugs. Now he lives on the streets.

The second example on the other hand ***implies a different meaning***: i.e. that he *was used* to the fact that he *was* your class' representative.
***Note:*** "Used to" becomes an **adjective** in the second sentence!

> used to
>   (adj.)
>   1. made familiar with; accustomed to (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/used+to)

***ADDITIONALLY***, the correct form of the second *sentence/meaning* is:

> There was a time when he was used to ***being*** our class representative.

to be + used to conjugated in tempus_______"Use to" conjugated (there is no present tense)
To be used to something________________  used to be

He **is used to** something______________  (He uses to be) / **he is**
He **was used to** something_____________He **used to be**
He **had/s been used to** sth____________  He **had/s used to be**

PPS: Even: "He ***used to be used to being*** the class representative" is, though very awkward, theoretically, grammatically correct to describe what you are saying in the second example but with the implication that he still is the class representative but for some reason (dementia) no longer is used to this.

REFERENCE:

> Usage note: used to / be used to
>   Do not confuse used to do something with be used to something.
>   You use used to do something to talk about something that happened regularly or was the case in the past, but is not now:I used to smoke, but I gave up a couple of years ago.
>   You use be used to something/to doing something to talk about something that you are familiar with so that it no longer seems new or strange to you:We’re used to the noise from the traffic now. ◇ I’m used to getting up early. You can also use get used to something:Don’t worry — you’ll soon get used to his sense of humour. ◇ I didn’t think I could ever get used to living in a big city after living in the country.

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/used-to

Comment: I suppose the first is syntactically correct, but it really should be "There was a time when he was our class representative."  Or "He used to be our class representative."

Comment: Okay. I was just fixing some formating which was quite messed up. Pls elaborate why the second one is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: "was" and "used to be" are both verbs.  There should only be one.

Comment: @HotLicks https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-m_used-be-used-to.htm http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/used+to http://www.thefreedictionary.com/used+to

Comment: @HotLicks much more eloquently phrased in the section where OLD WARNS you NOT to confuse ***used to*** with ***be used to*** i will/can copy that explanation with a link into my answer.

Comment: The usage above *is not* the same as "used to" in the references you give.

Comment: (Though I suppose if you parsed #2 as meaning "There was a time when he was used AS our class representative," then it would be OK.  But that has an entirely different meaning from the first sentence.)

Comment: I see a fault now which i previously just stumbled over but which i then ignored since i wasn't sure this is nevertheless not the fault you "elaborated" The mistake lies in "was used to *being*..." instead of "was used to be".

Comment: Once again, "There was a time when he was used to being our class representative" has an entirely different meaning from the first sentence.  (And it's awkward besides.)

Comment: @HotLicks that it has a different meaning as the original sentence is what stood in my answer from the very beginning. Awkward or not it is correct, probably what the OP asked about and very likely what other people might search for.

Comment: The OP said "Which one is a proper replacement of the above sentence?" where the "above sentence" is "There was a time when he was our class representative."

Comment: this meaning was also covered with " he was "**familiar** with the situation"

Comment: @HotLicks should have moved this to chat long ago but i guess we are at the end equal how. Yes, I could have just answered the first one is the propper replacement. I decided to answer the question which is intrinsic to the problem instead. Why? And why have i heard the other one as well? What is wrong with the other one? .